# Why is this didBeginContact Function causing the application to lag?

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit, xcode7

In my didBeginContact function I detect collision between a dragon and bullet.

Inside didBeginContact I assign two actions to the dragon. The first is the move to the left side of the screen, the second action is to send him across the screen.

The problem lies in the next line of code. When i call the function resetBullet, it causes a slight lag when the bullet hits the dragon. If i remove the resetBullet function, the lag is gone when the dragon and bullet come into contact.

Here is the didBeginContact and resetBullet

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let firstBody = contact.bodyA
    let secondBody = contact.bodyB
    if firstBody.categoryBitMask == bulletCategory && secondBody.categoryBitMask == dragonCategory || firstBody.categoryBitMask == dragonCategory && secondBody.categoryBitMask == bulletCategory{
       dragonNode.runAction(SKAction.moveTo(loadRandSpawnLeft(), duration: 0.0))
       dragonNode.runAction(SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width, dragonNode.position.y), duration: 5))
        //resetBullet()
        view?.userInteractionEnabled = true
    }

}

func resetBullet(){

        let resetBulletAction = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width * 0.5385, self.frame.size.height * 0.175), duration: 0.0)

        bulletNode.runAction(resetBulletAction)
        bulletNode.zRotation = 0
        view?.userInteractionEnabled = true
}
```

Comment: the fps of the application runs around 60.1, but when the bullet makes contact with the dragon it immediately drops to 50 or lower

Comment: Firstly, every time you call resetullet, you re-create the SKAction resetBulletAction - why not create it once and just re-use it? This probably won't account for the lag - is this in the simulator or on a device?

Comment: lag is on both, ill try that though @SteveIves